# Artin's primitive roots conjecture

Tags: analytic-number-theory

in this [link](http://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/perucca/perucca_artin.pdf) there is a short text about Artin's primitive roots conjecture.in part 4:

where $\sum\limits_{nsquarefree} {\frac{{\mu \left( n \right)}}{{\left[ {{K_n}:Q} \right]}}}$ come from?

what is $Q\left( {{\zeta _q},{a^{\frac{1}{q}}}} \right)
  $?

if there is some one that want to help me more please leave a comment then I give you my email address.thanks a lot

Comment: $Q$ is the rationals. $\zeta_q=e^{2\pi i/q}$ is a primitive $q$th root of unity. $Q(\zeta_q,a^{1/q})$ is the smallest field containing the rationals and $\zeta_q$ and $a^{1/q}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you very much. can you help me more? is it possible look at my other questions about least primitive roots?

Comment: I think if you have a lot of questions you are best off sitting down with someone to go through them. I also think you may be biting off more than you can chew, trying to understand very complicated things when there are basic underlying concepts you aren't familiar with. One step at a time. Take an introductory Analytic Number Theory text, and/or an introductory Algebraic Number Theory text (and probably a Field Theory text, first), and see how well you do, going through them. And if that's too hard, try an Elementary Number Theory text, and introductory abstract algebra, even linear algebra.

Comment: I did help you on one of them. If you have more, post them, and maybe someone will help you.